# Salesforce Data Loader for SFMC to import a CSV file

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I came across something called salesforce data loader - https://marcloudconsulting.com/sf-basics/salesforce-data-loader. But I cannout find this in AppExchnage. I had a few questions-

1. Have anyone of you used the data loader for SFMC, to import CSV file into Data extension ?(Note :I know in SFMC we have FTP for importing data, but wanted to check about data loader for one of our usecase)
2. There is another data loader I found on AppExchnage - https://www.jitterbit.com/. Have anyone of you used this for SFMC?

Thanks!

Comment: Data Loader is for Salesforce CRM, not Marketing Cloud, and why would you want to use a third party app when you can upload from a csv file directly into a Data Extension?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Our stakeholders don't have access to SFMC, to  upload a file to data extension or to FTP. Hence was thinking if data loader is of some help